# SATA SSD not detected after installing Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, xubuntu, ssd

I have an NVMe M.2 256 GB drive and a 240 GB SATA SSD with Windows
on the NVMe M.2 drive. I tried to install Xubuntu 18.04 on the SATA SSD.

The installation was successful, but after rebooting, the SATA SSD is not detected by BIOS. I tried clearing CMOS and tested the SSD on another PC. The SATA SSD was not detected on  the other system too.

Comment: Are you aware that *flavors* of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that is EOL.  (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ or a recent UWN - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses highlights the EOL notices for Lubuntu/Ubuntu-MATE/Kubuntu/Ubuntu-Budgie; Xubuntu didn't announce EOL but refer https://xubuntu.org/release/18-04/ you'll see it's 29 April 2021)

Answer (score 0):

Ι resolved the issue by turning of my PC, unplugging the SSD and plugging it back again.